# Getting numbers within a range from a gaussian_kde_resample array

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, gaussian

I have a `gaussian_kde.resample` array. I don't know if it is a numpy array so that I can use numpy functions.

I had the data `0<x<=0.5` of 3000 variables and I used

```
kde = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(x) # can also mention bandwidth here (x,bandwidth)
sample = kde.resample(100000) # returns 100,000 values that follow the prob distribution of "x"
```

This gave me a sample of data that follows the probability distribution of `"x"`. But the problem is, no matter what bandwidth I try to select, I get very few negative values in my `"sample"`. **`I only want values within the range 0 < sample <= 0.5`**

I tried to do:

```
 sample = np.array(sample) # to convert this to a numpy array
 keep = 0<sample<=0.5
 sample = sample[keep] # using the binary conditions
```

But this does not work! How can I remove the negative values in my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the return value of `kde.resample` is a numpy array, so you do not need to reconvert it.

The problem lies in the line (**Edit**: No, it doesn't. This should work!)

```
keep = 0 < sample <= 0.5
```

It does not do what you would think. Try:

```
keep = (0 < sample) * (sample <= 0.5)
```

Comment: I would like to know how the & didn't work and * did??

Comment: My bad, I was wrong when claiming the line wouldn't work. It really should. (I didn't realise python interpreted the chained comparison as a special case without casting to bool in between.)

Comment: And yes, there is no difference between & and * in this case. (So, actually jonnybazookatone's answer is better and more correct than mine!)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can check what type it is by using the 'type' call within python:

```
x = kde.resample(10000)
type(x)
numpy.ndarray
```

Secondly, it should be working in the way you wrote, but I would be more explicit in your binary condition:

```
print x
array([[ 1.42935658, 4.79293343, 4.2725778 , ..., 2.35775067, 1.69647609]]) 
x.size
10000
y = x[(x>1.5) & (x<4)]
```

which you can see, does the correct binary conditions and removes the values >1.5 and <4:

```
print y
array([ 2.95451084, 2.62400183, 2.79426449, ..., 2.35775067, 1.69647609])
y.size
5676
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm answering about 3 years late, but this may be useful for future reference.

The catch is that while `kde.resample(100000)` technically returns a NumPy array, this array actually contains another array(!), and that gets in the way of all the attempts to use indexing to get subsets of the sample. To get the array that the `resample()` method probably *should* have returned all along, do this instead:

```
sample = kde.resample(100000)[0]
```

The array variable `sample` should then have all 100000 samples, and indexing this array should work as expected.

Why SciPy does it this way, I don't know. This misfeature doesn't even appear to be documented.